# Initialize a CLLocation object in swift with latitude and longitude

Tags: swift, latitude-longitude, cllocation, cllocationdistance, cllocationcoordinate2d

In objective C (I have no experience with it) you can initialize a CLLocation object with latitude and longitude likes this:

```
CLLocation *myLocation = [[CLLocation alloc]  initWithLatitude:your_latitiude_value longitude:your_longitude_value];
```

But how do I do it in Swift?

I tried this,

```
let loc_coords = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: your_latitiude_value, longitude: your_longitude_value)

let loc = CLLocation().coordinate(loc_coords)
```

But I get this error:

Cannot invoke "coordinate" with an argument list of type '(CLLocationCoordiate2D)'

I need it to be a CLLocation object as I want to use the distanceFromLocation method within the locationManager.

Hope you can help, thanks!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I am not near my Mac to test it but the following should be working. Just pass your *lat* and *lon* values to the CLLocaion initializer like this:

```
let myLocation = CLLocation(latitude: your_latitiude_value, longitude: your_longitude_value)
```

For reference you can check the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocation/initWithLatitude:longitude:)

Comment: Yup, you got it, and you pressed return before I did (I went and verified it in a Playground, so I'm sure it's correct.)

Comment: Bah of course, thats quiet logical. But thanks a lot!

Answer (score 14):

If all you want is the initializer that takes a lat and long, your code can look like this:

```
let latitude: CLLocationDegrees = 37.2
let longitude: CLLocationDegrees = 22.9

let location: CLLocation = CLLocation(latitude: latitude, 
  longitude: longitude)
```

There are other initializers that take more parameters, but you didn't ask about those.